# Null Pointer Exception accessing Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

```
val opt2 :Option[DataFrame]= None

val result:Option[DataFrame] =opt2.getOrElse(None)
if (!result.isEmpty) {
result.show()
}
```

If i don't use getOrElse and use get instead , I am getting Null pointer exception.

If i use getOrElse , i m getting type Mismatch in result .How to fix. Also is there is any method like creatingEmpty Dataframe.

Comment: Try this `spark.emptyDataFrame`

Comment: Try this `import org.apache.spark.sql._` , `import org.apache.spark.sql.types._`, `spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], StructType(Array(StructField( "example", DataTypes.StringType ) ) ))`

Answer (score 0):

Spark provide pre-defined function to declare empty `dataframe`.

Please note, In below code `spark` in `SparkSession`.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> val df = spark.emptyDataFrame
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []

scala> df.show()
++
||
++
++
```